# Is it safe to install an electric fireplace in front of a decommissioned gas fireplace?

Tags: electrical, walls, gas, fireplace

I have a gas fireplace that I’ve not used in 7 yrs and I’m trying to update it to an electric fireplace. My contractor thinks it’s better to just cap the gas line and build a new fireplace wall with a new electric insert right in front of the gas fireplace up to the ceiling to cover up this existing gas fireplace. That way, no demo needed. Is this safe? Would this fail during inspection at resale?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't answer the inspection question, but having the gas capped behind a wall reduces options for you or a future buyer. Someone else might _want_ a gas fireplace and having the line readily accessible makes it obvious that this will be an easy switch.

Answer (score 1):

Cap the gas line outside or where it originates from its source so there is no chance of having a leak inside a wall or other enclosed space.

Have the chimney capped as well, so there is no chance of an animal falling in and dying behind a closed in wall.

This will admittedly limit your options if there should be a desire to return to a gas fireplace.  You have to ask yourself if you wish to do that.

As far as safe.  If done in the above manner it is safe and does not require extensive demo.   I have done the same to my own fireplace. (My wife says she does not have any desire to burn anything in it any more...decision made.)

Answer (score 0):

As both an Electrician and GSR Engineer in the UK, I can confirm with your Contractors recommendation, in terms of Regulations it completely complies with current standards, as such would pass any inspections. Enjoy your new Fire.